# Set alarm from Android 4.4 Kitkat

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-4.4-kitkat

In [Android 4.4 APIs page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) I read:

> When you set your app's targetSdkVersion to "19" or higher, alarms
>   that you create using either set() or setRepeating() will be inexact.
>
> [CUT]
>
> This inexact batching behavior applies only to updated apps. If you've
>   set the targetSdkVersion to "18" or lower, your alarms will continue
>   behave as they have on previous versions when running on Android 4.4.

In my application I need exact time alarm and I updated targetSdkVersion to "19". Is it correct the following code? Also if I set targetSdkVersion to "19" in phone with previous versions does the "old" method AlarmManager.set continue to work in the same way?

```
private void setAlarm (long ms){
    final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiverAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, ms, pi);
    } else {
        setAlarmFromKitkat(am, ms, pi);
    }
}

@TargetApi(19)
private void setAlarmFromKitkat(AlarmManager am, long ms, PendingIntent pi){
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, ms, pi);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Google failed to describe in more details:

1. for targetSDKVersion<19, "set" will be exact no matter the device is running on KitKat or earlier versions.
2. for targetSDKVersion>=19, "set" will be exact for device running < KitKat. But it will be inexact for device running KitKat.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 4.1.2 and uninstalled 4.4 from my ADT.
I set  "Build Target" to 4.1.2 and cleaned and rebuilt my app and have reinstalled apk to mobile.

However, the behavior is still inexact.

I paste the output from `adb shell dumpsys alarm` below:

RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{426941b0 type 0 net.coolbie.alarmclock}

```
   type=0 when=+4m46s480ms repeatInterval=0 count=0

   operation=PendingIntent{42553668: PendingIntentRecord{42a6cc38 net.coolbie.alarmclock broadcastIntent}}
```

You can see "when" is +4m up there, but which triggerTime is just 8 seconds.

```
long triggerTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Toast.makeText(mContext, "gap is:"+(triggerTime-currentTime)/1000,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);  
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext.getApplicationContext(),  
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendIntent);
```